# Is sending plain text HTML as just the plain text bad?

Tags: html, undefined-behavior

If I put:

```html
Welcome
```

Instead of:

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Welcome
  </body>
</html>
```

In my `index.html`, will that cause problems on some browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers rely on the HTTP [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header to determine how content should be parsed.

"Sending as plain text" usually refers to using `Content-Type: text/plain`, but I assume your index.html is always sent as `text/html`, and the question is about the contents of the file only.

Using `Content-Type: text/html` invokes the HTML parser, which produces almost the same DOM for both inputs, except for the `DOCTYPE` declaration (assuming you meant `<!DOCTYPE html>`, not DOCKTYPE).

In general, leaving out the DOCTYPE puts the page in the so-called ["quirks mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), which has [a number of effects in certain edge-cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

When a browser tries to [construct the DOM tree](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tree-construction) it will find itself with the [stack of open elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#stack-of-open-elements) empty. Thus the [insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#insertion-mode) will be set to *initial*, as stated in the reference link:

> The insertion mode is a state variable that controls the primary
> operation of the tree construction stage.
> Initially, the insertion mode is "initial".

So, you get to [Initial insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-initial-insertion-mode) and follow a series of *Anything else* cases that, as they go through several insertion modes, automatically proceed to create and close `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags and, within the latter, append your plain text.

However know that if you send just plain text with, for example, a .txt file the browser will treat also any eventual tag as plain text and wrap everything into a `<pre>` tag, since the content-type will be likely set to `text/plain` and the browser assumes you want to see everything as plain text.

Instead in your case putting plain text in an .html file will still set the content-type to `text/html` making the browser recognize eventual tags written there, without wrapping your code into a `<pre>` tag.
So in the last case there will be no difference in the DOM tree created by the two contents shown in your question.

Except actually for one: in your case the `DOCTYPE` declaration is omitted and this will make the browser render your page using a [Quirk mode](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/serving-xhtml/index.en#quirks) instead of a standard one, which may lead to [unwanted results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior).